# Canvas line drawing animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new learner of animation using `HTML5` Canvas. I am struggling to create line drawing animation in a canvas with desired length of a line.

Here is the code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
  height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
draw();
update();

function draw() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(100, 100);
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  context.stroke();
}

function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  x = x + 1;
  y = y + 1;
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The line is growing on Canvas in the above code. But how to achieve that the 200px wide line and animate the movement in x and y direction. And the same animation with multiple lines using for loop and move them in different direction.

Check the reference image ....
[image]

Need to move each line in a different direction

Thanks in advance

[image]

Find a new reference image which i want to achieve

Comment: To clarify, if we number the lines in your reference image from 1 to n, then do you want the odd numbered lines to go in one direction (clockwise perhaps) and the even numbered lines to go in the other direction (counter-clockwise) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I think you are describing...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.width = 400,
    height = canvas.height = 220,
    xcenter = 200,
    ycenter = 110,
    radius = 0,
    radiusmax = 100,
    start_angle1 = 0,
    start_angle2 = 0;

  function toRadians(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  function draw(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x1, y1);
    context.lineTo(x2, y2);
    context.stroke();
  }

  function drawWheel(xc, yc, start_angle, count, rad) {
    var inc = 360 / count;
    for (var angle = start_angle; angle < start_angle + 180; angle += inc) {
      var x = Math.cos(toRadians(angle)) * rad;
      var y = Math.sin(toRadians(angle)) * rad;
      draw(xc - x, yc - y, xc + x, yc + y);
    }
  }

  function update() {
    start_angle1 += 0.1;
    start_angle2 -= 0.1;
    if(radius<radiusmax) radius++;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    drawWheel(xcenter, ycenter, start_angle1, 40, radius);
    drawWheel(xcenter, ycenter, start_angle2, 40, radius);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }


  update();
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: 1. How to randomize the line length ?
2. How to make lines needs to draw over and over to touch the screen width  and height..If any lines touch the boundry.. then again it would start from the initial position.. ?

NOTE: I changed x and y randomize. but it gives a strange pattern.

Comment: draw(Math.random()*width - x, Math.random()*height - y, xc + x, yc + y);

Above is the changed code, to randomize the x and y position. and also i add a new reference image in the question

Comment: ok, i've created something that is a little more interesting - I'll paste it into a new answer below...

Answer (score 5):

You need to either use transforms or a bit of trigonometry.

### Transforms

For each frame:

- Reset transforms and translate to center
- Clear canvas
- Draw line from center to the right
- Rotate x angle
- Repeat from step 2 until all lines are drawn

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = c.width>>1;
var centerY = c.height>>1;
var maxLength = Math.min(centerX, centerY); // use the shortest direction for demo
var currentLength = 0;                      // current length, for animation
var lenStep = 1;                            // "speed" of animation

function render() {
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, centerX, centerY);
  ctx.clearRect(-centerX, -centerY, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  for(var angle = 0, step = 0.1; angle < Math.PI * 2; angle += step) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(currentLength, 0);
    ctx.rotate(step);
  }
  ctx.stroke();  // stroke all at once
}

(function loop() {
  render();
  currentLength += lenStep;
  if (currentLength < maxLength) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

You can use transformation different ways, but since you're learning I kept it simple in the above code.

### Trigonometry

You can also calculate the line angles manually using trigonometry. Also here you can use different approaches, ie. if you want to use delta values, vectors or brute force using the math implicit.

For each frame:

- Reset transforms and translate to center
- Clear canvas
- Calculate angle and direction for each line
- Draw line

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = c.width>>1;
var centerY = c.height>>1;
var maxLength = Math.min(centerX, centerY); // use the shortest direction for demo
var currentLength = 0;                      // current length, for animation
var lenStep = 1;                            // "speed" of animation

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, centerX, centerY);

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(-centerX, -centerY, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  for(var angle = 0, step = 0.1; angle < Math.PI * 2; angle += step) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(currentLength * Math.cos(angle), currentLength * Math.sin(angle));
  }
  ctx.stroke();  // stroke all at once
}

(function loop() {
  render();
  currentLength += lenStep;
  if (currentLength < maxLength) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

*Bonus animation to play around with (using the same basis as above):*

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});
var centerX = c.width>>1;
var centerY = c.height>>1;

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, centerX, centerY);
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
ctx.shadowBlur = 16;

function render(time) {
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.77;
  ctx.fillRect(-500, -500, 1000, 1000);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rotate(0.025);
  ctx.shadowColor = "hsl(" + time*0.1 + ",100%,75%)";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 16;
  
  for(var angle = 0, step = Math.PI / ((time % 200) + 50); angle < Math.PI * 2; angle += step) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    var len = 150 + 150 * Math.cos(time*0.0001618*angle*Math.tan(time*0.00025)) * Math.sin(time*0.01);
    ctx.lineTo(len * Math.cos(angle), len * Math.sin(angle));
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
  ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, -centerX, -centerY);
  ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, -centerX, -centerY);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}

function loop(time) {
  render(time);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
body {margin:0;background:#222}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=640 height=640></canvas>
```

Comment: Great work..espeacially the bonus animation... It shows me that a lot to learn.. Thank you for sharing...

Answer (score 1):

This is one that is a variable length emerging pattern. It has a length array element for each spoke in the wheel that grows at a different rate. You can play with the settings to vary the results:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var xcenter = width/4;
var ycenter = height/2;
var radius;
var time;

if(width>height) {
    radius = height*0.4;
}
else {
    radius = width*0.4;
}

var start_angle1 = 0;
var start_angle2 = 0;

function toRadians (angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}
function draw(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1,y1);
  context.lineTo(x2,y2);
  context.stroke();
}
var radmax=width;
var rads = [];
var radsinc = [];
function drawWheel(xc,yc,start_angle,count,rad) {
    var inc = 360/count;
    var i=0;
    for(var angle=start_angle; angle < start_angle+180; angle +=inc) {
        var x = Math.cos(toRadians(angle)) * rads[rad+i];
        var y = Math.sin(toRadians(angle)) * rads[rad+i];
        draw(xc-x,yc-y,xc+x,yc+y);
        rads[rad+i] += radsinc[i];
        if(rads[rad+i] > radmax) rads[rad+i] = 1;
        i++;
    }
}
function update() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var dt = now - (time || now);
    time = now;
    start_angle1 += (dt/1000) * 10;
    start_angle2 -= (dt/1000) * 10;
    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);                
    drawWheel(xcenter,ycenter,start_angle1,50,0);     
    drawWheel(xcenter,ycenter,start_angle2,50,50);     
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
function init() {
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
        rads[i] = 0;
        radsinc[i] = Math.random() * 10;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
  init();
  update();
};
```

```css
html, body {
            margin: 0px;

        }
        canvas {
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, this is really interesting... This is what i really want to... learned a lot about canvas..but still out there.. Thank you again..